# Iterate through treemap to match keys and values

Tags: java, loops, treemap

Why isn't it accounting for both keys and values within both treemaps? I'm trying to see if the treemaps are EXACTLY the same. I've been trying to figure out a way to use a for-each loop or entryset but I think there's just a small error somewhere... can anyone spot it?

```
public static boolean equals(SparseMatrix a, SparseMatrix b) {
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, <Integer, Double> entry : a.entrySet()) {
        if (a.equals(b)) {
            continue;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
        return true;

    }
}
```

---

I want to do it without a collection, set, or list... I want to do more of a for each loop over the keysets. Anyway?

P.S. the signature of the constructor cannot be changed...

Comment: Please don't remove the code from your questions. You are even less likely to get an answer if you do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access to `entry` key as `entry.getKey()` and value as `entry.getValue()` in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
private <K, V> void iterateOverMap(Map<K, V> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("key ->" + entry.getKey() + ", value->" + entry.getValue());
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to see if the treemaps are EXACTLY the same.

use Set's **`public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c)`** function:

```
Map<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, String>>data = new TreeMap<>();
Map<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, String>>data1 = new TreeMap<>();

// some input

Set<Map.Entry<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, String>>>entrySet = data.entrySet();
Set<Map.Entry<Integer, TreeMap<Integer, String>>>entrySet1 = data1.entrySet();

System.out.println(entrySet.containsAll(entrySet1)); // true if same
```